# How to Index the array by Timer and bind to View?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, timer

I have a label/text view that I want to change for the next "String" in my array every 180 seconds.
I have some array here that I need to use with `Timer` and a label/text view.

My question is what do I need to do?

```
@IBOutlet var ThisLabel: UILabel!

var array = ["a", "b", "c"]
var timer = Timer()

func labelShows() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 180, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Something here?
}

func action() {
    //what in this action?
    loveLabel.text = "Something here"
}
```

Comment: Keep an index property and increment it modulo the array size each time the timer fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check :

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var array = ["a", "b", "c"]
var i = 0
var timer = Timer()

func labelShows() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 180, target: self, selector: #selector(MyViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labelShows()
    action()
}

func action() {
    label.text = array[i]
    i = (i + 1) % array.count 
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's works) But when I build the project first again i see the basic name of label - Label. And then after 20 seconds it will be changed to "a"...  How to make that appeared only Strings from the array? And when you exit or collapse the application the counter did not start all over again but keep on?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Need to call action() in viewDidLoad

Comment: The 2nd line of `action` can be written more clearly as `i = (i + 1) % array.count`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a variable for storing the actual array index and increment it each time the timer runs. To avoud overflowing, check if the variable is equal to the array's count minus 1 and reset it.

```
var count = 0

func action() {
    loveLabel.text = array[count]

    if count == array.count - 1 {
        //reset
        count == 0
    } else {
        count += 1
    }
}
```